# React JS .map and assignment causing esLint error 'Assignment to property of function parameter. eslint(no param-reassign)'

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am trying to figure out how to fix a esLint error of the following

'Assignment to property of function parameter. eslint(no param-reassign)'

Here is my code so far

```
myArray.records.map(record => 
  record.subRecords.map(subRecord => (
    subRecord.transId = this.getIdCorrection(subRecord.transId)
  ))
))
```

I tried using cloneDeep and making another copy for map and reassign, the error is there there.

I read a few post but I am confused with how they are using filter.

I am pass an integer value and it passes an integer based on some business rules.

I am not sure how to get pass this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ESLint probably wants you to create and return a new object. Remember that `map` isn't for mutating the elements of an array, it's for creating a new array of items.

```
const newRecords = myArray.records.map(record => ({
...record,
subRecords: record.subRecords.map(subRecord => ({
   ...subRecord,
   transId: this.getIdCorrection(subRecord.transId)
  })
}))
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the help. I am getting 1 syntax error "Argument expression expected on the last curly bracket. Here my changes. Added a comma                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                 const newRecords = myArray.records.map(record => ({
...record,
subRecords: record.subRecords.map(subRecord => ({
   ...subRecord
   transId: this.getIdCorrection(subRecord.transId)
  })
}))

Comment: Good catch. I've amended the answer to include the missing comma!